# Blobstore upload stripping mime parts on Production but not Dev?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm trying to include some additional data in a blobstore upload which I can then process with the BlobInfo. According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/:

> When the Blobstore rewrites the user's request, the MIME parts of the uploaded files have their bodies emptied, and the blob key is added as a MIME part header. All other form fields and parts are preserved and passed to the upload handler.

This seems to be working fine on the Dev Server but not on the live AppEngine.

Having got the upload URL from the blobstore service, on the client-side I'm then doing:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("upload-request", JSON.stringify({
  myExtraData: "something"
}));

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
  formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
}

xhr.open("POST", uploadUrl);
xhr.send(formData);
```

And then trying to process it on the server side with:

```
log.warning("isMultipartContent: " + ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req));
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(req);
int count = 0;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  ++count;
  FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
  if (item.isFormField()) {
    log.warning("Got a form field: " + item.getFieldName());
  } else {
    log.warning("Got an uploaded file: " + item.getFieldName() +
        ", name = " + item.getName());
  }
}
log.warning("FileItem count = %s", count);
```

When I run this on the local Dev server, everything works perfectly and it happily logs both the form field part and the re-written (content-stripped) file part and a count of 2.

When I run it on the live App Engine, it logs only `isMultipart: true` and `FileItem count = 0`

It seems that the live server, contrary to the documentation, is stripping all the mime parts from the request.

Note, that the blobs are still retrievable with `blobstore.get{File,Blob}Infos(req)`, but I cannot access the additional data that was sent with the request.

Has anyone seen this before? Is this is a known bug or have I misinterpreted the docs? Does anyone know if the same is true in the Python runtime? Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Thanks,
Rich

(Apologies: this is cross-posted from the App Engine Google Group; only after I posted there did I read the thread about support moving here instead.)

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the reason?

Comment: I noticed the form fields are still sent as regular request parameters, so they can be accessed with `HttpServletRequest.getParameter(...)`.